# Google-Maps-for-Rails blank map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm running Ruby 1.9, Rails 3.2.8 and gmaps4rails 1.5.5. I have followed the Readme, double checked I have <%= yield :scripts %> in the footer and still I have a blank white box where the map should be with no errors. I have checked using Firebug and the Google JS, the gmaps4rails JS appearing to be loading and my controller's @json variable contains lats and longs. I'm just not sure what to check on next.

Why this might be the case how I can go about troubleshooting the problem?

Comment: damn you're the second to tell that. will check this

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug. are you able to reproduce it in a dummy app you'd push on github?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Did you find the issue

Comment: https://github.com/bewithjonam/gmaps4rails-rails3.2.8.git This is a dummy rails 3.2.8 application which has the same issue as described above. To add, the browser keeps showing the loading image, there is a empty maps box with nothing inside it and the last call made in the browser is to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_ads&cad=src:apiv3,ads:0. Waiting for a response